# Unmovable menu on scene

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I want to add a menu on my cocos2d scene, but I don't want to move it with scene's position. (I understand that, if we add something on scene, then that will move with scene, so please provide me any alternative solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you don't move the scene. Instead put your menu item on a layer within the scene and then the rest of what was in your scene in another layer, then move that layer instead of the whole scene.